# How can I strip down core-image-sato and remove selected apps/packages?

Tags: yocto, odroid

I want to build a stripped version of `core-image-sato` for `Odroid-C2`.
Currently, everything related to Openhanded Sato mobile environment gets into the image when I compile/build image using yocto.

I want to remove Leafpad, Shutdown, Media Player, Games/Puzzles etc but I want to keep the matchbox desktop. I don't want to remove entire desktop manager.

Can anyone please suggest a way how can I remove these apps?

I had a look at the following link: 
[How to strip down my Yocto Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457102/how-to-strip-down-my-yocto-linux)

But this is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: To remove a given package you can just `IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = "whatever"`

Comment: I tried removing packages using `IMAGE_INSTALL_remove` but that didn't work.

Comment: Which packages have you tried to remove? Where did you place the above sentence?

Comment: @danlor: I put that in `local.conf`. But the answer by @Ross Burton worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`core-image-sato` is an example, just write your own image recipe.  The `x11-sato` image feature is what pulls in all of Sato. Remove that and add `packagegroup-core-x11-sato-base` to `IMAGE_INSTALL` to install just the desktop.

Comment: It worked!! I didn't have to write my own image recipe, all I did as you suggested to remove `x11-sato` image feature and add `packagegroup-core-x11-sato-base`.
I edited `local.conf` and added `IMAGE_FEATURES_remove = " x11-sato"` and `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "packagegroup-core-x11-sato-base"`.

Comment: Awesome! small typo: add a space after the quote char: IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " packagegroup-core-x11-sato-base"